# sql server change notification and SqlDependency

Tags: sql-server-2008

I was looking for a better mechanism for notifying my desktop clients that a sql server table has changed. Exclude the option of an app server tier, I'm looking at solutions that fit into the existing thick client->Sql server model. I'm familiar with triggers and polling, but was hoping for something a bit smarter.

One option seems to be SqlDependency. I'm looking at that at the moment, but have seen a few mentions that it has "restrictions" and may be "unsuitable" for large numbers of changes. I've not found a lot of information on that, or many recent code examples.

What are you using for notification that a sql server table has been amended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a service, ie all chnages to tables go through it, then you are down to polling or dependancy. All dependancy does is hook into sql servers own table change code and fire a change event. The underlying mechanism is very simple, and can get swamped by a large number of changes, attempting to rationalise the changes in the event handler is problematic at best.

You might get somewhere with triggers to a "communications table", where you could add the rationalisation logic, then  use dependancy from there.

So instead of detecting a simple change to column1 in table1 you trigger an insert to an event record in your comms table.

It's going to be a PIA because you've excluded an app server tier, you've also drastically constrained your options for doing something efficient and nice.

Comment: Oh I'd have an app tier if I could. That's just not an option at the moment :/ There wasn't much info on the dependencies, just the odd cryptic note about it being a bit dodgy. Thanks for the advice I think I'm going with triggers to a couple of "communications" tables and just poll those.